# How do I reduce the number of characters in an input string/varchar in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I basically have two tables `tbl_feedback` and `tbl_notification` that both get values inserted in them through a stored procedure whenever a person submits a feedback.

What I'm aiming for is getting a "shortened" version of a `message` column inserted into `tbl_notification` (say 60 characters max) so a notification only shows a preview of the actual message.

Is this possible using a MySQL function or do I have to resort to handling it via PHP (shortening an output string before echoing it)

Comment: See the `LEFT` function.

Comment: Check this out https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-left-function.php

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, @shalithasenanayaka . All I needed to know was the function's name. The rest was simple googling.

Comment: Actually, the manual groups all string functions together under a single chapter, so I would argue that you didn't even need to know its name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LEFT` function was what I was looking for. *Thanks, Paul*.
I wish that google pointed me straight to this function.

[w3resource on LEFT function](https://w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-left-function.php)